# What is the general solution for the following second order ODE: $y-4x(x-\tanh(x))\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution to the following ODE:
$$y-4x(x-\tanh(x))\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0 \tag{1}$$
Since the equation involve the function ($y$) and its derivatives, I decided to "guess" a solution of the form $y=e^{p(x)}$. Therefore, the second derivative of the solution becomes $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d^2p}{dx^2}e^p+(\frac{dp}{dx})^2e^p$.
Making the substitution $q=\frac{dp}{dx}$ this equation becomes first order in $q$, or
$$\frac{dq}{dx}+q^2-\frac{1}{4x(x-\tanh(x))}=0 \tag{2}$$
However, from this point on, I got stuck.

I guess that the radical $\frac{1}{4x(x-\tanh(x))}$ may lead to a difficult or impossible integral, so the solution may just be written in the implicit form $q=\int f(x) dx$.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to solve this ODE analytically as it involves a nonlinear term and an implicit relationship between q and x. One possible approach to finding a numerical solution would be to use numerical integration methods, such as the Runge-Kutta method. In this method, you start with an initial guess for the value of q at some initial x and use the ODE to calculate q at successively larger values of x. The solution is then obtained by integrating the function q(x) with respect to x.

Alternatively, if you have access to a symbolic computation software like Mathematica, you could use the built-in function NDSolve to solve the ODE numerically. You would specify the ODE and the initial conditions, and the software would use numerical methods to find a numerical solution to the ODE.